# confusing exercise

Tags: subjunctives

> The patient's doctor strongly urges that he has an operation on his back as soon as his general health improves.

had to substitute has?

for 'had'  it fit the subjunctive mood condition? Why?

Comment: I'm afraid we permit only one topic at a time in questions.

Comment: @StoneyB okay I will ask separately, you can edit the question.

Comment: It is for you to edit the question down to whatever single topic is most important to you, and to indicate your reasons for your guess at the answer; that will allow us to address any misunderstanding directly, without instructing you in matters you already understand.

Comment: @StoneyB thank you so much, is it okay  now?

Answer (score 2):

Your instinct to employ a "subjunctive" is correct, but you want what traditional grammar called the "present subjunctive" rather than the "past subjunctive", which is identical with the infinitive/imperative form.

> . . . urges that he **have** an operation on his back . . .

None of these terms is very useful. "Subjunctive" doesn't mean anything in particular with respect to English grammar. The "past subjunctive" is "past" only in the sense that it employs the form conventionally called "past". And the "present subjunctive" in contemporary English is used only in what is called the "mandative subjunctive", as the head of clauses which act as complements to certain verbs of obligation, demand, request, or entreaty, where it always has *future* reference:

> The law requires that he **submit** this form within 3 days of the occurrence.
>   She pleaded that she **be** permitted to withdraw.

It also hangs on in some fossilized expressions like "Long **live** the Queen".

Answer (score 1):

I'm not positive I understand what you are asking.  That said, I would write the sentence as:

> The patient's doctor strongly urges that he **have** an operation on his back as soon as his general health improves.

The subjunctive mood is appropriate because it is unknown whether the operation will occur or not.